# usar return en una función javascript para regresar un json obtenido por AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

estoy usando jquery para enviar un JSON a un archivo php por ajax, todo esto dentro de una función javascript pero cuando uso `return` para devolver los el json convertido en un objeto sólo retorna undefined

este es el js

```
function createFieldSearch (datos) {
    var res;
    $.ajax({
      data:  {"datos":datos},
      url:   'php/createFieldSearch.php',
      type:  'post'
    }).done(function (response) {
        res = JSON.parse(response);     
    });
    return res;
}

var respuesta = createFieldSearch('{"color":"rojo"}');
console.log(respuesta);
```

y este el php

```
<?php
    $datos = $_POST["datos"];
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo json_encode($datos, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
?>
```

lo que quiero es almacenar el objeto en una variable para luego poder usarlo como lo traté de hacer aquí

```
var respuesta = createFieldSearch('{"color":"rojo"}');
console.log(respuesta);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu función estas usando **.done** para la devolución de llamada. Puedes modificar el return de la siguiente forma:

```
function createFieldSearch(datos) {
    return $.ajax({
        data: { "datos": datos },
        url: 'example.php',
        type: 'post'
    }).done(function (response) {
        return JSON.parse(response);
    });
}
```

Para usar la función sería de este modo:

```
createFieldSearch('{"color":"rojo"}').done(function(respuesta){
    // Respuesta
    console.log(respuesta);
})
```

Comment: Tu respuesta hace justo lo que necesitaba hacer al final para poder usar el objeto y acceder a sus elementos use el JSON.parse fuera de la función,
quedó de la siguiente manera
function createFieldSearch(datos) {
     return $.ajax({
         data: { "datos": datos },
         url: 'php/createFieldSearch.php',
         type: 'post'
     }).done(function (response) {
         return response;
     });
 }

 createFieldSearch('{"color":"rojo","numero":4}')
 .done(function(respuesta){
     var doc = JSON.parse(respuesta);
     console.log(doc.numero)
 })

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        function createFieldSearch (datos) {
     //   $("#myForm").submit(function() {

          //var url = $('#myForm').attr('action');
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          //url: url,
          //data: $("#myForm").serialize(), 
          data:  {"datos":datos},
          url:   'php/createFieldSearch.php',
          async: false,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) { 
          alert(data); 

            //  show_lista_asistencias(id);
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, text, error){
                // Displaying if there are any errors
                 // $('#result').html(error);
              alert('no se pudo add los datos');
            }
        });
        return false;
      //});
    }
        </script>
```

y en el archivo php

```
<?php
    $datos = $_POST["datos"];


    //header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo json_encode("los datos son $datos  ");
?>
```

Comment: esta respuesta realmente no ayuda a solucionar mi problematica